# Declare pointer to a structure as iterator in a for loop

Tags: c

I am trying to use a pointer to a structure as iterator in a for loop but it is giving me the error "error #20: identifier "z" is undefined" as if I have to declare it first than using it in the for loop and I don't know how to do that.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int id;
    double low;
    char *str;
} Zone;
```

```
void print_table(Zone zones[], int len, double hr_max)
{

    for (Zone *z = zones; z < zones + len; z++)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, compiles fine for me. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I am using Ccstudio, I am not sure if that makes a difference :(

Comment: Are you using C99?

Comment: [Hope this helps](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/other-microcontrollers-group/other/f/other-microcontrollers-forum/746728/ccs-tm4c1231h6pge-enabling-c99-in-ccs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler is from the stone age and therefore can't handle declarations inside a `for` loop. You need to enable C99 support or newer. Apparently this "CCS" thing is using a gcc version older than 5.0.0, when gcc was default set to `-std=gnu90`, so I guess your compiler is outdated by over 10 years.

In general I would strongly recommend not to use dysfunctional Eclipse spawns provided by silicon vendors. These tools are *horrible*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) You are completely right. I changed the setup to support C99 (link below ) and it worked. Thank you https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/other-microcontrollers-group/other/f/other-microcontrollers-forum/746728/ccs-tm4c1231h6pge-enabling-c99-in-ccs